# How can I add entries into a Resource file programatically?

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

I have a bunch of database entries for use as resources in a web application.

I would like to put these entries into a resource (.resx) file, but there are over a thousand db entries and I would like to write a quick program to create the .resx file.

How can I create this file?  I've looked at the ResourceWriter class, but when I tried that it corrupted my .resx file.

Can anyone provide any ideas or code samples?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that you need a resx file? You can add resources as "plain" files, the only difference would be that you wouldn't get to access them through nicely-named variables.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - good point, although I really would like to access them through strongly typed variables.  I've got it all going now, just need to create that .resx file.

Comment: I don't think that the resx file alone gets you your strongly typed variables.  Along with your Resources.resx file, Visual Studio automatically code-gens a file called Resources.Designer.cs that does all of the strong-typing for you.  Even if you get your resx file in place, you'll still have to code-gen this file.  If you're able to code-gen the file (the hard part) then you might as well include the plain files and have the code-genned part target those.

Comment: resX files are just Xml files with a certain schema.

Comment: Thanks, good to know, that could also be an easy way to generate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a plain StringBuilder to construct the xml content you need and then save it to the file.

Comment: I thought about that, but initially dismissed it since I thought the PublicKeyToken was somehow unique to each entry.

Comment: I'll end up doing this way, but seems kind of ghetto, sure there isn't a cleaner way?

Comment: I think it a KISS way of doing things

Comment: True, when I think about it, would end up being about 10 lines of code.